# lastIndex of not returning expected result

Tags: scala

In the following code

```
val tag = "codingjavascript moremore2-evenmoreempty"
val codingSeparator = tag.indexOf("-")
println(s"${codingSeparator}")
val emptySeparator = tag.lastIndexOf("-",codingSeparator)
println(s"${emptySeparator}")
```

Why both `codingSeparator` and `emptySeparator` have value 26? Shouldn't `emptySeparator` be `-1` if search is started from index 26? I even tried `val emptySeparator = tag.lastIndexOf("-",codingSeparator+1)` but also gives the same result

output

```
tag: String = codingjavascript moremore2-evenmoreempty
codingSeparator: Int = 26
26
emptySeparator: Int = 26
26
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

take a look at java doc of `lastInfexOf` method:

```
/**
 * Searches in this String for the index of the specified string. The search for the string starts at the specified offset and moves towards the
 * beginning of this String.
 *
 * @param subString
 *            the string to find
 * @param start
 *            the starting offset
 * @return the index in this String of the specified string, -1 if the string isn't found
 *
 * @throws NullPointerException
 *              when string is null
 *
 * @see #lastIndexOf(int)
 * @see #lastIndexOf(int, int)
 * @see #lastIndexOf(String)
 * @see #lastIndexOf(String, int)
 */
public int lastIndexOf(String subString, int start) {
...
```

this method looking for substring from start **towards the beginning** of this String. But you expect what it moving from start to **the end** of String.

If you want find another separator, I think you should use `substring` :

```
val emptySeparator = tag.substring(codingSeparator + 1).indexOf("-")
println(s"$emptySeparator") // -1
```